# How to get actual URL and transform it in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, http, parsing, url

I want to get the actual URL, parse it and add the parameters - `param` and `value`. This is all I did, I don't know how to continue.

```
@Autowired
private HttpServletRequest request;

public String setParameter(String param, String value){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("&")
    .append(param)
    .append("=")
    .append(value);

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many options depending on the configuration/implementation/spring version you use.
The first option that I mentioned below will be probably the most suitable for your needs.

---

> First option

Make a method and pass request as parameter. You don't need to use StringBuilder (boilerplate code), but you can if you want/need to.

```
public String makeUrl(HttpServletRequest request, String param, String value) {
    return request.getRequestURL().toString() + "&" + param + "=" + value;
}
```

---

> Second option

To get current URL you can also use request bound to the current Thread by using

```
((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest()
```

and adding

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

to the `web.xml` file/by using suitable annotations in Spring Boot.

---

> Third option

You can use ServletUriComponentsBuilder/UriComponentsBuilder and build new URL using methods from documentation below.

Your example:

```
public String makeUrl(HttpServletRequest request, String param, String value) {
    ServletUriComponentsBuilder builder = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequestUri();
    builder.queryParam(param, value);
    URI uri = builder.build().toUri();
    return uri.toString();
}
```

Documentation:

[ServletUriComponentsBuilder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/support/ServletUriComponentsBuilder.html)

[UriComponentsBuilder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriComponentsBuilder.html)

Comment: Really thanks men it solve my problem,hope you have a nice day :D

Comment: No problem, same to you! :)